# vue router with Navigation Guards- next() not working

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-router, vue-cli

Protecting Vue Routes with Navigation Guards. 
The Navigation Guards is working when onload or refresh, but
the `next()` function is not working when accessing routes using `<router-link>`.

```
<router-link to="{ name: 'page1' }" >Page 1</router-link>
```

navigation guard codes.

```
{
   path: '/page1',
   component: page1,
   name: 'page1',
   meta: { auth: true },
   beforeEnter: (to, from, next) => {
     if (!store.state.roles.includes('is_superadmin')) {
            if (!store.state.firm_permissions.includes('can_have_fire_contractors')) {
                 console.log('success page1')
                 next({
                    name: "page0"
                 })
             } else {
                 next()
             }
      }
      next()
    },
 }
```

I can see the `console.log('success page1')` but the `next()` is not working...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add `return` after `next()`:

```
beforeEnter: (to, from, next) => {
     if (!store.state.roles.includes('is_superadmin')) {
            if (!store.state.firm_permissions.includes('can_have_fire_contractors')) {
                 console.log('success page1')
                 next({
                    name: "page0"
                 })
                 return // Add this
             } else {
                 next()
             }
      }
      next()
    },
```

Comment: otherwise the last `next()` after your `if` statement takes over..